# How to order comments by likes/dislikes in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

On my website people can thumbs up or thumbs down a comment.
To do this I use two tables:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE content
(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY(id),
content TEXT NOT NULL,
date date,
time time
)";
```

and

```
$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE ratings 
(
rating_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
rating VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL ,
id INT NOT NULL ,
ip VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
)";
```

The data stored in the ratings would be as follows:

```
Comment ID   like/dislike    user IP
1            l               86.42.173.83
1            d               86.42.173.43
2            l               86.42.173.79
2            l               86.42.173.34
2            d               86.42.173.22
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm finding it extremely difficult to create a SQL statement to order the comments by the amount of likes they have.

If anyone has any ideas on how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier if you stored likes as integers and not letters.

I added up the likes using a case statement and grouped by comment.

```
SELECT C.content, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN R.rating = 'l' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS overallRating
FROM content C
LEFT JOIN ratings R ON R.id = C.id
GROUP BY C.content
ORDER BY overallRating
```

Comment: Everything you said is true, but the question specified the number of likes, not the overall rating.

Comment: @DanBracuk Well the overall rating is the sum of likes minus the dislikes.  By removing `ELSE -1` from the query it would just add up the likes and ignore dislikes

Comment: Brilliant man! Worked like a charm! I just tweaked it to count the number of like rather than the overall rating! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

something like this will work

```
select content.text, count(*) likes
from content join ratings on content.id = ratings.id
group by context.text
order by likes
```